# download file from google firebase storage with CURL or WGET

Tags: linux, firebase, curl, firebase-storage, wget

We try to download a file from googles firebase storage from a linux machine  using CURL or WGET.

We do it like that:

```
curl -O https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket/o/file.jar?alt=media&tokena=token
```

or simple

```
wget https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket/o/file.jar?alt=media&tokena=token
```

The problem is the download is a stream

```
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55fc13cc0b00)
} [5 bytes data]
```

so at the end the connection left intact, and we don't no when the file is finished to download

```
Connection #0 to host firebasestorage.googleapis.com left intact
```

So the question is how can we download some public file from googles firebase storage without the use of gsutil, but with CURL or WGET or something else.

Comment: Does wget's `--no-http-keep-alive` option help?

Comment: With Wget, the download finishes, when the server stops sending data. Until then, it will keep downloading and storing to file. What exactly is the problem you're facing?